# Out Of Memory failed in JDeveloper 11.1.2.4

Tags: out-of-memory, jdeveloper, kill-process, taskmanager

I got Out Of Memory error in my JDeveloper 11.1.2.4

The program run nice but slowly at the first time, but at the second it's failed...

I have to kill the process often.

someone know the phenomenon?

Thanks